# Why isn't width:200px applied to this label?

Tags: html, css

In [this example](http://jsbin.com/usovix), I'm setting `width:200px` on form labels.
This is not being applied for some reason, and the field appears 0 width when viewed in Chrome Dev Tools.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`label` is an inline element, like a `span`. It does not have width, but flows with its content. To get it to behave like a `div`, you would have to instruct it to act like a block-level element:

```
display: block
```

From there, you could add width:

```
width: 200px;
float: left;
```

Comment: Thanks. I can never remember the css rules, what applies to which element, etc...

Answer (score 2):

As above, you need to get your label to behave like a `block` element to get it to respect your `width` declaration. The simplest way to do this is to set it to `inline-block` like this:

```
 #form label {
  width:200px;
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

Or, as @David mentions, float it left. [This article](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) describes getting this to work cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the label is an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display) so does not have a width property. To set the width you need to make it a block or inline-block element:

```
#form label {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Label is an inline element, so you cannot apply a fixed width to it (unless you change its display behavior). See here for a quick map of options/browser compatibility

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html